# Replace ./ with $PWD in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have string that may or may not start from ./, or may be just a ./
In that case I want to replace it with $PWD

Any help?

```
APP_FOLDER=./service
MODIFIED_APP_FOLDER= = $([[ $APP_FOLDER= './'* ]] && echo "${APP_FOLDER/'./'/"$PWD"}" || echo "$PWD/$APP_FOLDER")
```

Causes "Wrong substitution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not needed to use sub-shell expansion here with Bash:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf '%-10s %s\n' 'app_folder' 'modified_app_folder'
for app_folder in ./service foobar ./ /tmp/test; do
    modified_app_folder=${app_folder/#.\//$PWD/}
    printf '%-10s %s\n' "$app_folder" "$modified_app_folder"
done
```

Sample output:

```
app_folder modified_app_folder
./service  /home/lea/StackOverflow/service
foobar     foobar
./         /home/lea/StackOverflow/
/tmp/test  /tmp/test
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

Always pass your script to https://shelcheck.net before asking human help. Or use the command line:

```
$ shellcheck file
In file line 2:
MODIFIED_APP_FOLDER= = $([[ $APP_FOLDER= './'* ]] && echo "${APP_FOLDER/'./'/"$PWD"}" || echo "$PWD/$APP_FOLDER")
                    ^-- SC1007 (warning): Remove space after = if trying to assign a value (for empty string, use var='' ... ).
                       ^-- SC1009 (info): The mentioned syntax error was in this command expansion.
                         ^-- SC1073 (error): Couldn't parse this test expression. Fix to allow more checks.
                                       ^-- SC1108 (error): You need a space before and after the = .
                                          ^-- SC1072 (error): Expected comparison operator (don't wrap commands in []/[[]]). Fix any mentioned problems and try again.

For more information:
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1108 -- You need a space before and after...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1007 -- Remove space after = if trying to...
  https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC1072 -- Expected comparison operator (don...
```

Corrected code:

```
$ cat file
APP_FOLDER=./service
MODIFIED_APP_FOLDER=$([[ $APP_FOLDER == './'* ]] && echo "${APP_FOLDER/.\//"$PWD/"}" || echo "$PWD/$APP_FOLDER")
echo "$MODIFIED_APP_FOLDER"

$ bash file
/tmp/service
```

Comment: Fail with paths not starting with `./`

Comment: I'm newbie in bash, so that url is really helpfull!! Thanks a lot